# Помогите отправить запрос ajax в мой класс оброботчик LeftInfo

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

вот JS

```
 $('.read-more').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //
    var id_news = $(this).attr('data-id-news');

    $.ajax({
        url: "______.php",
        data: {id_news:id_news},
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Помилка читання інформації даної новини!");
        }
    })

});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите передать id_news в файл LeftInfo.php в метод
public function getFullNew()

даже незнаю что писать в url: "______.php", і как направить его в етот файл (((

Comment: Пишите полный путь с указанием домена.

Comment: а метод как указать?

Comment: Если у вас на php единая точка входа и роутер, то задайте там для определенного адреса вызов нужного метода из данного класса и в js соответственно используйте этот адрес для отправки/запроса данных.

Comment: можно поподробней?

Comment: А какой вы адрес вводите в браузере, чтобы увидеть нужную вам информацию? Такой же нужно писать и в ajax запросе (можно указать относительный путь)

Comment: мне надо передать дание ajax на файл LeftInfo.php в метод public function getFullNew()

Answer (score 0):

просто в запросе пишете `url:"../путь"`.

.. -везде ссылается на переход в родительскую папку.
Их можно сколько угодно писать:

```
../../../
```